# How to optimize Lucene.Net indexing

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I need to index around 10GB of data.  Each of my "documents" is pretty small, think basic info about a product, about 20 fields of data, most only a few words.  Only 1 column is indexed, the rest are stored.  I'm grabbing the data from text files, so that part is pretty fast.

Current indexing speed is only about 40mb per hour.  I've heard other people say they have achieved 100x faster than this.  For smaller files (around 20mb) the indexing goes quite fast (5 minutes).  However, when I have it loop through all of my data files (about 50 files totalling 10gb), as time goes on the growth of the index seems to slow down a lot.  Any ideas on how I can speed up the indexing, or what the optimal indexing speed is?

On a side note, I've noticed the API in the .Net port does not seem to contain all of the same methods as the original in Java...

Update--here are snippets of the indexing C# code:
First I set thing up:

```
            directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(@txtIndexFolder.Text, true);
            iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true);
            iwriter.SetMaxFieldLength(25000);
            iwriter.SetMergeFactor(1000);
            iwriter.SetMaxBufferedDocs(Convert.ToInt16(txtBuffer.Text));
```

Then read from a tab-delim data file:

```
    using (System.IO.TextReader tr = System.IO.File.OpenText(File))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] items = line.Split('\t');
```

Then create the fields and add the document to the index:

```
                fldName = new Field("Name", items[4], Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                doc.Add(fldName);
                fldUPC = new Field("UPC", items[10], Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO);
                doc.Add(fldUPC);
                string Contents = items[4] + " " + items[5] + " " + items[9] + " " + items[10] + " "  + items[11] + " " + items[23] + " " + items[24];
                fldContents = new Field("Contents", Contents, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED);
                doc.Add(fldContents);
                ...
                iwriter.AddDocument(doc);
```

Once its completely done indexing:

```
    iwriter.Optimize();
    iwriter.Close();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on (a) total number of documents (b) analyzer used (c) length of indexed field? Also just to confirm, are you re-using IndexWriter?

Comment: Total number documents roughly 10,000,000.  StandardAnalyzer.  Yes I am re-using IndexWriter and Document, but was unable to re-use Field as the C# port does not seem to implement Field.SetValue.

Comment: I actually just loaded this on a dedicated server with SetMaxBufferDocs at 25000.  Its very fast in the beginning...but after 8 hrs now the index is only about 150mb.

Comment: That seems really slow.  Can you post your indexing code?

Comment: ok, I updated the question with the indexing code.  Funny thing is now, for the past two hours, its been chugging away, but hasn't updated the index files at all...

Comment: actually just occurred to me...the index size -should- slow down as time goes on, and the common words are already in it...I probably need a better way to track index progress.

Comment: Creating "Contents" by concatenating multiple strings with '+' could be a problem if these strings are large. You could create it with StringBuilder. In fact, you could add Field("Contents", item[4]) Field("Contents", item[5]), to the document to avoid creating single "Contents" string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I had downloaded a 3 yr old version of Lucene that is prominently linked to for some reason from the home page of the project...downloaded the most recent Lucene source code, compiled, used the new DLL, fixed about everything.  The documentation kinda sucks, but the price is right and its real fast.

From a [helpful blog](http://jsprunger.com/getting-started-with-lucene-net/)

> First things first, you have to add
>   the Lucene libraries to your project.
>   On the Lucene.NET web site, you’ll see
>   the most recent release builds of
>   Lucene. These are two years old. **Do
>   not grab them, they have some bugs.**
>   There has not been an official release
>   of Lucene for some time, probably due
>   to resource constraints of the
>   maintainers. Use Subversion (or
>   TortoiseSVN) to browse around and grab
>   the most recently updated Lucene.NET
>   code from the Apache SVN Repository.
>   The solution and projects are Visual
>   Studio 2005 and .NET 2.0, but I
>   upgraded the projects to Visual Studio
>   2008 without any issues.  I was able
>   to build the solution without any
>   errors. Go to the bin directory, grab
>   the Lucene.Net dll and add it to your
>   project.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on the marked answer above related to a 3 year old version, I would highly recommend installing the Visual Studio extension for NuGet Package Manager when adding Lucene.NET to your projects.  It should add the most recent DLL version for you unless you need a specific later version.